# PHP compare between multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [section1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item1] => 'green'
                    [item2] => 'red'
                    [item3] => 'purple'
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item1] => 'green'
                    [item2] => 'black'
                    [item3] => 'purple'
                )
        )
    [section2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item1] => 'orange'
                    [item2] => 'pink'
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item1] => 'gray'
                    [item2] => 'pink'
                    [item3] => 'yellow'
                )
        )
```

I am trying to count the matches between the `1` and `1` so in the example above the result would be `2` for section 1 and 1 for section2. I am then trying to output this as a new array. I have this so far which is loopiung throough the correct sections but am lost from here

```
foreach($array1 as $array1item) {

    foreach ($array1item as $array1nesteditem) {
        echo 'test | ';
    }

}
```

Am I on the right track by doing this nested loop? Or is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: How is it suppose to be 2? What exactly are you trying to compare? section1[1] with section2[1]...?
Are you just trying to compare the two arrays `section1` and `section2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $array1item) {
    $newArray[$key] = count(array_intersect(...$array1item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to u_mulder's but with an additional index check.

```
<?php

$data =
[
    'one' => [
        [
            'pink',
            'orange',
            'purple'
        ],
        [
            'pink',
            'red',
            'purple'
        ]
    ],
    'two' => [
        [
            'yellow',
            'turquoise',
        ],
        [
            'yellow',
            'cyan',
        ]
    ]
];
$counts = array_map(function($v) {
    return count(array_intersect_assoc(...$v));
}, $data);

var_export($counts);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'one' => 2,
  'two' => 1,
)
```